# Fair Shift Distribution

Tags: python, or-tools

I have a slightly modified version of nurse_sat
https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/master/examples/python/nurses_sat.py
where I have a dictionary of key - value pares of (day, nurse, shift) = BoolVar
I want to make it so all nurses have same amount of each shift.

E.G: Let's assume that we have 30 days, and there are 3 shifts per day {0, 1, 2} and we have 3 nurses {a, b, c}
I would like to have all nurses do 10 of shift 0, 10 of shift 2 and 10 of shift 3.

The way I am trying to achieve this is:

```
fairshift = {}
for j in range(num_nurses):
 for k in range(num_shifts):
  fairshift[(j,k)] = sum(shifts[(i, j, k)] for i in range(num_days))
```

In theory, that should give me how many particular shift a nurse had. E.G: fairshift[(0, 0)] should have the number of the 0 shifts Nurse A had throughout the week. And then to make them equal, I did something like this:

```
for k in range(num_shifts):
 solver.Add(min([fairshift[(j, k)] for j in range(num_nurses)]) == max([fairshift[(j,k)] for j in range(num_nurses)]))
```

So that max number of k shifts a nurse had would be equal to the min one and if num_days is 30 they all should have 10 shifts of shift k.

However, I can't get it to work and I am unsure of why. To have IntVar instead of _SumArray, I did something like this:

```
for j in range(num_nurses):
 for k in range(num_shifts):
  fairshift[(j,k)] = solver.NewIntVar(0, num_days, "%i,%i" % (j,k))
  solver.Add(fairshift[(j,k)] == sum(shifts[(i, j, k)] for i in range(num_days)))
```

In the case of min .== max, it works but gives wrong results. I think I'm summing something wrong, but I am unsure what it is.

Comment: First quick comment, you should have `max(fair_shifts) - min(fair_shifts) <= 1` to account for the case when the num of shifts is not a multiple of the number of persons.

Comment: But the real problem is that you cannot use the min() and max() operators of python as this is expanded in something that is not understood by the model. It works for sum() but not for min/max. You should use `model.AddMaxEquality()` and `model.AddMinEquality()` with intermediate integer variables.

Comment: Hello @Laurent Perron, I thought since max([IntVar]) returns IntVar, it would work as well, it's now fixed. I tried AddMaxEquality earlier, but I was getting an error but _SumArray not having index, but it worked with assigning IntVars to fairshift[(j, k)]. Thank you! I'd be happy to accept it if you'd like to have this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fairshift = {}
for n in range(num_nurses):
  for s in range(num_shifts):
    sum_of_shifts[(n, s)] = model.NewIntVar(0, num_days, 'sum_of_shifts_%i_%i' % (n, s))
    model.Add(sum_of_shifts[(n, s)] == sum(shifts[(d, n, s)] for d in range(num_days)))


for s in range(num_shifts):
  min_fair_shift = model.NewIntVar(0, num_days, 'min_fair_shift_%i' % s)
  max_fair_shift = model.NewIntVar(0, num_days, 'max_fair_shift_%i' % s)
  model.AddMinEquality(min_fair_shift, [sum_of_shifts[(n, s)] for n in range(num_nurses)])
  model.AddMaxEquality(max_fair_shift, [sum_of_shifts[(n, s)] for n in range(num_nurses)]) 

  model.Add(max_fair_shift - min_fair_shift <= 1)
```