# Or-Tools CpSolver Get Minimum and Maximum Sum or absolute

Tags: python, c#, linear-programming, or-tools, mixed-integer-programming

I am new to Mixed Integer programming. i have used gurobi tool before to build this model. but beacuse of the cost i wanted to switch to or-tools, but i was not able to do the same logic.

the problem i am trying to solve is to minimize the differences of the sum of variables.

in other word, i have employess I want to distribute them equally on a schedule keeping their assignment fair to everyone.

so i have build my model following these steps:

1- create IntVar for every employee per shift per day.
2- i have added a constrain that every employee should have one shift every day

now i want my model to solve against sum of number of shits attended by every employee and try to minimize the difference between the minimum and the maximum shifts attended by the employees.

this can be achieved by doing it in multiple ways

1- get the min and the max of the linearExpr (the sum of the employees) and minimize the difference
2- or , the absolute sum of  the differences between the average of shifts and every number of shifts attended by every employee.

Unfortunately, I was not able to find max, min, or absolute implementation for this.

if you guys have a suggestion that i can reach this please explain.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions that you are looking for are:

- [AddMaxEquality](https://google.github.io/or-tools/python/ortools/sat/python/cp_model.html#cp_model.CpModel.AddMaxEquality)
- [AddMinEquality](https://google.github.io/or-tools/python/ortools/sat/python/cp_model.html#cp_model.CpModel.AddMinEquality)
- [AddAbsEquality](https://google.github.io/or-tools/python/ortools/sat/python/cp_model.html#cp_model.CpModel.AddAbsEquality)

But in this official example, they minimize the delta to the average:

https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/master/examples/python/reallocate_sat.py

Here is a simplified version:

```py
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model

model = cp_model.CpModel()

total = 35
n = 5
avg = total // n

ints = [model.NewIntVar(0, 10, str(i)) for i in range(n)]
delta = model.NewIntVar(0, total, "delta")

for i in ints:
    model.Add(i >= avg - delta)
    model.Add(i <= avg + delta)

model.Minimize(delta)

solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
solver.Solve(model)

print([solver.Value(i) for i in ints])
```

Comment: AddMaxEquality and AddMinEquality and AddAbsEquality take IntVar as parameters, in my case i have LinearExp of SumArray. after my search i found that in C++ it supports AddLinMinEquality and AddLinMaxEquality and AddLinAbsEauality which accepts LinearExpr. but not sure why its not available in C#

Could you help me in this or a twerk, or away to convert LinearExp or SumArray to IntVar?

Comment: I think this might be the solution using python, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53356121/fair-shift-distribution

Comment: Yes, I believe you have to create intermediate variables and equal them to each linearexp

Comment: AddLinMaxEquality is experimental code. It is not ready to be exported in all languages.